# SwiftUI crashes with List element

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I've build a tabbed app which consists of 4 tabs, but sometimes the app crashes unexpectedly. Digging deeper into the problem I found the following warning in the console:

> [TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its
>   visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy
>   (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a
>   window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to
>   load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view
>   bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and
>   will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout
>   passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at
>   UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the
>   debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this
>   action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has
>   been added to a window. Table view:
>   <_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView:
>   0x7ff9ec08b000; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 375 768);
>   clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0,
>   0}; contentSize: {375, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 83, 0};
>   dataSource: (null)>

I managed to strip down my application to find the root of this message and it seems that `List{}` causes these warnings. The stripped app is simply a **Tabbed App* and the `ContentView.swift` the file looks like follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            List {
                Text("text")
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image("first")
                    Text("First")
                }
            }
            .tag(0)
            Text("Second View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("second")
                        Text("Second")
                    }
            }
            .tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Has anyone else one of these experiences? Could someone explain my which my app crashes?

PS: I find it quiet hard to debug SwiftUI apps because of the builder syntax.

Comment: what version of Xcode do you use? Code looks normal, does this code snippet crashes too?

Comment: Works for me in Xcode 11.3.1 / iOS 13.3

Comment: Works in XCode 11.3 and / iOS 13.3. Could you please update your xcode version and then try to run your code.

Comment: Confirm crash with Xcode **11.2 Preview only!** Works on Simulator/Device iOS 13.2

Comment: My Xcode version is 11.3.1 (11C504) and the Simulator version is 11.3.1 (SimulatorApp-912.5.1 SimulatorKit-570.3 CoreSimulator-681.17.2).

It runs without a crash on the simulator (but with the mentioned warning) but it crashes very often on my iPhone.

Very annoying because SwiftUI makes it nearly undebuggable. ... Any help or idea would be fine.